# At which points of the domain does $f(x)$ has limit?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb R$

$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{|q|+1} + sin(\frac{1}{|q|}), & x \in \mathbb{Q}\\
Cos(\pi x), & x \in \mathbb{Q^c}   
\end{cases}$.

(I) We first try to check the limit at ${x=0}$

Then we see that a sequence $\frac{p_n}{q_n} \to 0$ where $ q_n \to \infty $ where $f(\frac{p_n}{q_n}) \to 0$

However $lim_{x \to 0}cos(\pi x) = 1$

Hence the limit at $x=0$ doesn't exist.

(II) We then try to check the limit of the function at $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q^c}$

Then we see that a sequence $\frac{p_n}{q_n} \to \alpha$ where $ q_n \to \infty $ where $f(\frac{p_n}{q_n}) \to 0$

However $lim_{x \to \alpha}cos(\pi x) = cos(\pi \alpha) = 0$ which is only possible if $x=(2n-1)/2$

So limit doesn't exist at all irrational points

(III) How to show that limit exists or doesn't exist at the rational points of this function?

Comment: Observe that as $x\to a$ via rational points function tends to $0$ (prove this). Also the function never takes the value $0$ and then you can conclude.

Comment: Isn't this the way to find the limit at the irrational points as $(p_n/q_n) \to \alpha$ then $q_n \to \infty$. How do I find the limits at rational points?

Comment: No this is not the way to find limit at irrational points, but it is a way to find limit as $x\to a$ through rational points. Whether $a$ itself is rational or irrational does not matter.